# Incorrectly including cloo in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, cloo, opencl.net

I'm trying to get **[this](http://dhruba.name/2012/10/14/opencl-cookbook-hello-world-using-c-cloo-host-binding/)** demo to build but I get this error

[image]

I've tried this with mono and visual studio 2010, same problem

The error occurs on line

```
program.Build(null, null, null, IntPtr.Zero);
```

**EDIT**

C#

```
using System;
using Cloo;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ClooTest
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            // pick first platform
            ComputePlatform platform = ComputePlatform.Platforms[0];

            // create context with all gpu devices
            ComputeContext context = new ComputeContext(ComputeDeviceTypes.Gpu,
                                                        new ComputeContextPropertyList(platform), null, IntPtr.Zero);

            // create a command queue with first gpu found
            ComputeCommandQueue queue = new ComputeCommandQueue
            (
                context,
                context.Devices[0], 
                ComputeCommandQueueFlags.None
            );

            // load opencl source
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("kernels.cl");
            string clSource = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            streamReader.Close();

            // create program with opencl source
            ComputeProgram program = new ComputeProgram(context, clSource);

            // compile opencl source
            program.Build(null, null, null, IntPtr.Zero);

            // load chosen kernel from program
            ComputeKernel kernel = program.CreateKernel("helloWorld");

            // create a ten integer array and its length
            int[] message = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            int messageSize = message.Length;

            // allocate a memory buffer with the message (the int array)
            ComputeBuffer<int> messageBuffer = new ComputeBuffer<int>(context,
                                                                      ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadOnly | ComputeMemoryFlags.UseHostPointer, message);

            kernel.SetMemoryArgument(0, messageBuffer); // set the integer array
            kernel.SetValueArgument(1, messageSize); // set the array size

            // execute kernel
            queue.ExecuteTask(kernel, null);

            // wait for completion
            queue.Finish();
        }
    }
}
```

OpenCL

```
kernel void helloWorld(global read_only int* message, int messageSize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < messageSize; i++) {
        printf("%d", message[i]);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
[image: debug]

Comment: Does your hardware support openCL?

Comment: I've been using opencl on that computer through OpenCL.net . I wanted to try out Cloo as well. OpenCL.Net seems to work OK, is there anything else I should check for?

Comment: Your question should "provide specific code to reproduce the problem", not a link to an example somewhere

Comment: What does clSource contain? I'd take a guess that your closing your stream too early

Comment: I added an image of the screen when I hit a breakpoint on that troublesome line. clSource appears to have the correct code string in it

Comment: on the other hand, when I remove 'printf("%d", message[i]);' from the opencl code, there is no exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah print probably isn't very well supported. I would suggest performing your "Hello world" with some simple number crunching instead. Maybe something like:

```
kernel void IncrementNumber(global float4 *celldata_in, global float4 *celldata_out) {
    int index = get_global_id(0);

    float4 a = celldata_in[index];
    a.w = a.w + 1;

    celldata_out[index] = a;  
}
```